# c++ Puzzle like tetris algorithm for random pieces

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, puzzle, tetris

So there's a mini-game on which I try to find a solving solution given the following description:

You have a board 6x4 on which you are given random "tetris" pieces to put on to fill the board. When the board is filled, you have succesfully finished the game. You start with the board empty and you fill it up as you play.
The piece that is not the "best fit" can be thrown away, so you can replace it with another random one. The main goal is to finish the game with as minimal "replacements" as possible for the best score.
Another rule is that you cannot rotate the pieces, so they can only be placed as they are given. You either put it on the board, or throw it away.
You can get the same piece for X times in a row, as it's RNG based.

**Later Edit**: I came up with another approach on keeping track of the pieces on the board as the "I" shape was being tracked as rotated as well, so I hardcoded the possible arrays they can be placed into, so here's the new version:

```
typedef struct StructSlotsInfo
{
    bool    isPosBusy;
    BYTE    shapeIndex;
};

int MAX_SLOTS_NR = 24;

StructSlotsInfo* piecesSlots = (StructSlotsInfo*)malloc(sizeof(StructSlotsInfo) * MAX_SLOTS_NR);

enum EnumShapes
{
    SHAPE_NONE, // declared for indexing purposes so I won't go i+1;
    SHAPE_1, // "I" shape 1x3
    SHAPE_2, // single square
    SHAPE_3, // "L" shape 2x2
    SHAPE_4, // "L" shape - rotated version
    SHAPE_5, // big square 2x2
    SHAPE_6, // "Z" shape
    SHAPE_7, // 3x2 shape - rectangle
};

bool IsValidPosition(BYTE shapePos, BYTE shapeType)
{
    bool finalReturn = false;

    BYTE posList[7][8] = {
        { SHAPE_1, 12, 0, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_2, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_3, 17, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_4, 17, 0, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_5, 17, 0, 1, 6, 7, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_6, 16, 0, 1, 7, 8, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_7, 16, 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 },
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(posList) / sizeof(posList[0]); i++)
    {
        if (posList[i][0] == shapeType)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < posList[i][1]; j++)
            {
                if (shapePos == j
                    && piecesSlots[j + posList[i][2]].shapeIndex == 0
                    && piecesSlots[j + posList[i][3]].shapeIndex == 0
                    && piecesSlots[j + posList[i][4]].shapeIndex == 0
                    && piecesSlots[j + posList[i][5]].shapeIndex == 0
                    && piecesSlots[j + posList[i][6]].shapeIndex == 0
                    && piecesSlots[j + posList[i][7]].shapeIndex == 0)
                {
                    finalReturn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return finalReturn;
}

void PlaceShape(BYTE shapePos, BYTE shapeType)
{
    BYTE posList[7][7] = {
        { SHAPE_1, 0, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_3, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_4, 0, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_5, 0, 1, 6, 7, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_6, 0, 1, 7, 8, 0, 0 },
        { SHAPE_7, 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 },
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(posList) / sizeof(posList[0]); i++)
    {
        if (posList[i][0] == shapeType)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
            {
                if (j > 1 && posList[i][j] == 0)
                    continue;

                if (posList[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    piecesSlots[shapePos].isPosBusy = true;
                    piecesSlots[shapePos].shapeIndex = shapeType;
                }
                else
                {
                    piecesSlots[shapePos + posList[i][j]].isPosBusy = false;
                    piecesSlots[shapePos + posList[i][j]].shapeIndex = shapeType;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void CheckCompletedBoard() {

    bool isBoardCompleted = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SLOTS_NR; i++)
    {
        if (piecesSlots[i].shapeIndex == 0)
        {
            isBoardCompleted = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isBoardCompleted) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SLOTS_NR; i++)
        {
            piecesSlots[i].isPosBusy = false;
            piecesSlots[i].shapeIndex = 0;
        }
        cout << "The game is complete, resetted the board." << endl;
    }

}
```

As I wrote again the shapes part, I've commented what shape is what index in their enumeration.

Now here I am a bit stuck. How should I assign them into the "puzzleBoard" array and iterate for the best possibilities? I'm sorry for that big of a question, but I've tried finding something for like 2 days now.

The board itself completed looks like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYwvO.jpg ( there are not all the pieces on the board, it's just an example as they are randomly given to you as you throw away the ones that don't fit ) and here's the complete list of the pieces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oyU1.jpg

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could search github for a solution: tetris robot site:github.com

Comment: BTW, "tetris" pieces are known as "tetrominos" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) but it seems that your pieces are not (excepted two) regular tetrominos, rather "polyminos" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Gowiser, I've looked around github for puzzle & tetris solvers, but there's nothing I could find like this one, based at around that logic of play.
jferard Thanks for the heads-up, I'm not that familiar with the terms, so I've tried explaining as clear as I could. English is not my native language :P.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** I misread the question and assumed it was a C question. My answer is therefore written in C, nor C++ (oops). I think the basic principles still apply though.

I can't give you a complete answer because that will take a long time but I will give you some pointers.

The first problem you have is that all you know about `arrayTemp` is that it is an array. You don't know how big it is and you don't know its width and height. So each of your shapes needs to have that information as well as the pattern.

```
struct Shape 
{
    int width;
    int height;
    BYTE pattern[];
};
```

I would create a function to fill in the data (the below code is not guaranteed bug free, I'm typing it direct into the answer without testing).

```
struct Shape* makeShape(int with, int height, char* pattern)
{
    struct Shape* ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);
    ret->pattern  = malloc(width * height);
    for (i = 0 ; i < width * height ; ++i)
    {
        ret->pattern[i] = pattern[i]
    }
    return ret;
}

void freeShape(struct Shape* shape)
{
    if (shape != NULL)
    {
        free(shape->pattern);
    }
    free(shape);
}

// example

    struct Shape *zShape = makeShape(3, 2, shapeZ);

// Do stuff

    freeShape(zShape);
```

Then when you need to copy the shape into your puzzleBoard, you need to first calculate the source and the destination indexes based on the dimensions of the shape and the dimensions of the puzzle board and then decide if you can copy it. Then, if you can copy it, you do the copy.

Here is a function to check if a `BYTE` in a source shape can be copied to the destination shape

```
bool cellCanBeCopied(struct Shape* sourceShape, int sourceRow, int sourceCol, struct Shape* destShape, int destRow, int destCol)
{
    // Assume rows and cols are within the respective bounds of the shapes
    // Leave the checks as an exercise for the reader

    int sourceCell = sourceShape->width * sourceRow + sourceCol;
    // If the cell is empty in the source shape, it doesn't matter
    // if it's occupied in the dest shape
    if (sourceShape->pattern[sourceCell] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    int destCell = destShape->width * destRow + destCol;
    return destShape=>pattern[destCell] == 0;
}
```

And here is how to use it to check if a whole shape can be copied.

```
bool shapeCanBeCopied(struct Shape* sourceShapestruct Shape* destShape, int destRow, int destCol)
{
    // First check that the source shape will fit in the destination shape
    if (destRow + sourceShape->height > destShape->height
        || destCol + sourceShape->width > destShape->width)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int sourceRow = 0 ; sourceRow < sourceShape.height ; ++sourceRow)
    {
        for (int sourceCol = 0 ; sourceCol < sourceShape.height ; ++sourceCol)
        {
            if (!cellCanBeCopied(sourceShape, sourceRow, sourceCol, destShape, destRow + sourceRow, destCol + souceCol))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You may ask how you do the same when the destination is the puzzle board? Well, you can just store the puzzle board in a shape like everything else.

Comment: Thanks alot for the guidance! I've put the checks in place now :). Indeed it's easier to keep track of the shapes via structs and such. I'll see what I can come up with for the solving part...That's the hardest logic in my opinion, as I have to do it with the minimal moves as possible.

Comment: @Aerya I've just noticed this is a C++ question not a C question. In C++ you would  probably create a class but the basic principles are the same.

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed all the parts that needed to be fixed & converted, thanks alot! Now I'll start testing things.

Comment: I've cleaned up the code and made it more understandable now ( edited the main post ), took another approach on keeping track of the parts as some shapes were counted as "rotated" as being valid, which were not.

Thanks alot for your time!